# Re-execute the web service request after refreshing the token with retrofit in interceptor

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, token, interceptor

I have an Android application with a retrofit client and an interceptor that check for the 401 response code (Token expired) so after it catch's this error i can execute an other web service that will refresh my token using the refresh token given to me when i did the sign in, and all this works well and smoothly.

My problem is how to recall the first request after receiving the new valid token and saving it.

```
 class AuthenticationInterceptorRefreshToken(var client: OkHttpClient?, var retrofit: Retrofit?) :
    Interceptor {
    private val TAG = "AuthenticationIntercept"
    var authenticationUseCase = AuthenticationUseCase()

    @SuppressLint("CheckResult")
    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        var request = chain.request()
        val builder = request.newBuilder()
        request = builder.build()
        val response = chain.proceed(request)
        if (response.code() == 401) {
            Log.e(TAG, "intercept: Refresh it")
            if (Paper.book().contains(Const.USER_CONNECTED)) {
                val currentToken: String =
                    (Paper.book().read(Const.USER_CONNECTED) as LoginResponse).refreshToken
                authenticationUseCase.refreshToken(RefreshTokenRequest(currentToken))
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(
                        {
                            when (it) {
                                is AuthenticationUseCase.LoginResult.Success -> {
                                    val new =
                                        (Paper.book().read(Const.USER_CONNECTED) as LoginResponse)
                                    val gson = Gson()
                                    val data = gson.fromJson(
                                        gson.toJson(it.userResponse.data),
                                        NewTokenResponse::class.java
                                    )
                                    new.token = data.token
                                    Paper.book().write(Const.USER_CONNECTED, new)
                                    Log.e(TAG, "handleRefreshToken Success New: $new")
                                    //todo re-execute the web service
                                }
                                is AuthenticationUseCase.LoginResult.Failure -> {
                                    Log.e(
                                        TAG,
                                        "handleRefreshToken Failure: ${it.throwable.localizedMessage}"
                                    )
                                    logout()
                                }
                            }

                        }, {
                            Log.e(TAG, "intercept: Here something BAD: $it")
                        })
                return response
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "intercept No data found: ")
                context.startActivity(
                    Intent(
                        context,
                        WelcomingActivity::class.java
                    ).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
                )
            }
            return response
        }
        return response
    }


    @SuppressLint("CheckResult")
    private fun logout() {
        authenticationUseCase.logout(
            LogoutRequest(
                (Paper.book().read(Const.USER_CONNECTED) as LoginResponse).user.id,
                (Paper.book().read(Const.USER_CONNECTED) as LoginResponse).refreshToken
            )
        ).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe {
                when (it) {
                    is AuthenticationUseCase.LoginResult.Success -> {
                        Log.e(TAG, "showLogoutDialog: Success: ${it.userResponse}")
                        Paper.book().delete(Const.USER_CONNECTED)
                        GlobalUtils.navigateToActivity(
                            context as Activity,
                            context,
                            WelcomingActivity::class.java
                        )
                    }
                    is AuthenticationUseCase.LoginResult.Failure -> {
                        if (it.throwable.localizedMessage.contains("500")) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "getConnectedUser: Problem here 2")
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Server error...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show()
                        }
                        Log.e(TAG, "showLogoutDialog: Failure:  ${it.throwable}")
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

And this is my retrofit client that i am using in every call to the server

```
object RetrofitClient {
    private var retrofit: Retrofit? = null
    private var client: OkHttpClient? = null
    fun build(): ItchekApi {
        if (retrofit == null) {
            if (client == null)
                client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .addInterceptor(
                        AuthenticationInterceptorRefreshToken(
                            client,
                            retrofit
                        )
                    )
                    .addInterceptor(HeaderInterceptor())
                    .connectTimeout(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .readTimeout(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .writeTimeout(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .build()

            retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .client(client)
//                .addConverterFactory(NullOnEmptyConverterFactory())
                .baseUrl(ApiEndPoints.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.createAsync())
                .build()
        }
        return retrofit!!.create(ItchekApi::class.java)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have got the new Access Token, what you need to do now is to create a new Request with the new Access Token

Replace your `//todo re-execute the web service` with this

```
if (new.token != null) {
   val newRequest = chain.request().newBuilder()
                    .addHeader("Authorization", new.token)
                    .build()
   return chain.proceed(newRequest)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but i want to say that after i did what you recommended, I got a throwed exception Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException when this  line is executed Log.e(TAG, "intercept: Here something BAD: $it"), So i can't tell for sure if this response fixed my error correctly or no

Comment: oh i see, you have defined the subscriber on the main thread, so above code is executed on the main thread while it should be executed on another thread.
So what you need to do now is to wrap above code on another thread. Like what you did when requesting a new Access Token.